# Using dynamic xpath in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am using a variable say xpathvar in the XSLT whose value will be supplied at the time of call to XSLT. How can i achieve this?
My XSLT file looks like -

```
<xsl:param name="xpathvar"/>
<xsl:param name="keyxpath"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <listofResults>
    <xsl:for-each select="$xpathvar">
    <keyvalues><xsl:value-of select="xalan:evaluate(substring-before($keyxpath,'||'))"/></keyvalues>
    <keyvalues><xsl:value-of select="xalan:evaluate(substring-after($keyxpath,'||'))"/></keyvalues>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </listofResults>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I mention the variable in the for-each, it throws error. Please guide how can I achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: please, provide a complete source XML document (but as minimal as possible) and describe what output results are required -- depending on this it may be possible to use pure XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Global xsl:param containing xpath expression string](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/86986-global-xsl-param-containing-xpath-expression-string) it can't be done purely with plain old XSLT, you need to use the **evaluate** extension see: [Xalan evaluate expression](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#evaluate)

Comment: I wouldn't give so strong answer. Take a look at this "walker" template implementation for a XPath subset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530707/in-xslt-how-come-i-cant-set-the-select-attribute-of-a-value-of-using-xslattrib

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this can be done like this you must use xpath so example would be

```
<template match="Node[name=$xpathvar]" />


<xsl:for-each select="*[name()=$xpathvar]">
</xsl:for-each>
```

I think it does not let you use the variable directly because it is not a nodeset.

Comment: If I apply this, it does not identify the xpath of variable. My XML is <EMPLOYEES> <EMPTYPE> <TYPE>Permanent</TYPE> <EMPDATA> <EMPNO>361686</EMPNO> <ENAME>RATS</ENAME> <JOB>ASE</JOB> <HIREDATE>17-DEC-80</HIREDATE> <SAL>800</SAL> </EMPDATA> <EMPDATA> <EMPNO>361687</EMPNO> <ENAME>RATS</ENAME> <JOB>ASE</JOB> <HIREDATE>17-DEC-80</HIREDATE> <SAL>800</SAL> </EMPDATA> </EMPTYPE> </EMPLOYEES> and the output after applying the content given above is Permanent 361686 RATS ASE 17-DEC-80 800 361687 RATS ASE 17-DEC-80 800 Any pointers will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> If I mention the variable in the
>   for-each, it throws error

In XSLT 1.0 (it looks you are using Xalan), you can iterate over node sets, only. So `$xpathvar` should be an instance of node set data type.

In XSLT 2.0 you can iterate over sequence (including scalar values).

Also, if the string containing the "dynamic" XPath expression is simple enough (only QName test step, maybe positional predicates) this could be done (as is already answered in SO) with standar XSLT.