# How to store xpath in variable and use it with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use a variable that has xpath in for-each. But it is giving me an error that Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

NodeName is defined as

```
<xsl:variable name="NodeName" select="name(.)"/>

<xsl:variable name="SyncPath" 
              select="concat('/combinedxml/com.csc_PolicySyncRs/',$NodeName)"/>
```

and here is for-each loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="$SyncPath/*">
```

Comment: Could you please provide nicely-formatted XSLT fragment you're referring to?

Comment: Could you show how $NodeName is being defined?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377811/using-dynamic-xpath-in-xslt or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682151/xslvariable-as-xpath-value-for-other-xsl-tag or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551526/is-it-possible-to-use-a-dynamic-xpath-expression-in-a-xslt-style-sheet or one of http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+xslt+dynamic+xpath

Comment: For this case use: `<xsl:variable name="SyncPath"                select="/combinedxml/com.csc_PolicySyncRs/*[name()=$NodeName]"/>`

Comment: @Alejandro: Sorry, I saw your comment after submitting my answer. I prefer to answer such questions -- don't have enough time to find a duplicate. And actually, redundancy is not always a bad thing.

Comment: @Dimitre: No problem. I'd just commented because I didn't want to left the OP without a simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take wild guess and assume you're interested in converting variable to node set in order to use it later in XPath. This could be done using extension function `exsl:node-set()`. The [documentation](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) have examples of usage.

Quote:

> This use case shows the result of
>   using exsl:node-set() to convert a
>   result tree fragment to a node-set.
>
> **source**

```
<doc>
   <one />
   <two />
   <three />
   <four />
</doc>
```

> **stylesheet**

```
<!--  Test exslt:node-set applied to a result tree fragment  -->
<xsl:variable name="tree">
   <a>
      <b>
         <c>
            <d />
         </c>
      </b>
   </a>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <out>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(exslt:node-set(//*))" />
   </out>
</xsl:template>
```

> **result**

```
<out xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">5</out>
```

Comment: exslt is undefined even after adding the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:variable name="SyncPath"
    select="/combinedxml/com.csc_PolicySyncRs/*[name()=$NodeName]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 1.0 (and indeed 2.0) has no standard facility for constructing an XPath expression as a string and then evaluating it. Many processors have an extension function to do this, variously called dyn:evaluate, saxon:evaluate, etc.