# How can I read text as xpath expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-2.0

Ill much appreciate if any one can help me in finding a way to read a text as xpath expression

e.g. this is my xml document

```
<abc>
    <XYZ>
        <include>/citizen[./marital_status[text() ='married']]</include>
    </XYZ>
</abc>
```

and I am writing a stylesheet

```
    <xsl:template match="abc">
        <xsl:call-template name="evaluate">
            <xsl:with-param name="include">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$include"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
```

The problem here is that the text of `<include>` element here is something i want to be an xpath expression in `<xsl:apply-templates select="$include"/>`. this will give me citizens who are married but here i just get the string `"/citizen[./marital_status[text() ='married']]"` itself as a result. Is there anypossible way of doing it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I do not believe it is possible with xslt 1.0 without using http://www.exslt.org/ or other extension functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551526/is-it-possible-to-use-a-dynamic-xpath-expression-in-a-xslt-style-sheet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377811/using-dynamic-xpath-in-xslt

Answer (score 1):

Check what's available in your chosen XSLT processor: see if it has some kind of xx:evaluate() extension function. If not, or if you want a portable solution, the alternative is to generate a stylesheet (or stylesheet module) containing the relevant expression, and then compile and execute the stylesheet.