# Building dynamical xPath

Tags: jsp, xslt, xpath, el, dynamically-generated

I have to make xPath dynamical, based on my request attributes in XSL file making JSP using expression language. So now I have this thing:

```
<xsl:variable name="xPath">@name='${categoryName}'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="tar:products/category[$xPath]/subcategory">
```

But this doesn't work. So the question is how to get round this problem and make xPath work?

---

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tar:products SYSTEM "products.dtd" >
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='products2HTML.xsl'?>
<tar:products xmlns:tar="http://www.epam.com/products"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.epam.com/products products.xsd ">
<category name="Electronics">
    <subcategory name="mp3">
        <product name="iPod 4g">
            <provider>Apple</provider>
            <model>Qd246</model>
            <dateOfIssue>11-11-2012</dateOfIssue>
            <color>white</color>
            <notInStock/>
        </product>
        <product name="Cowon">
            <provider>Cowon</provider>
            <model>sF223</model>
            <dateOfIssue>13-12-2012</dateOfIssue>
            <color>black</color>
            <price>13456</price>
        </product>
        <product name="IRiver">
            <provider>IRiver e30</provider>
            <model>Ir234</model>
            <dateOfIssue>13-12-2012</dateOfIssue>
            <color>black</color>
            <price>13456</price>
        </product>
    </subcategory>
    <subcategory name="Computers">
        <product name="iMac">
            <provider>Apple</provider>
            <model>Mm232</model>
            <dateOfIssue>20-02-2012</dateOfIssue>
            <color>silver</color>
            <notInStock/>
        </product>
        <product name="PC">
            <provider>Acer</provider>
            <model>Ae135</model>
            <dateOfIssue>22-11-2012</dateOfIssue>
            <color>black</color>
            <price>13456</price>
        </product>
    </subcategory>
</category>
<category name="Toys">
    <subcategory name="Electronical toys">
        <product name="Cat">
            <provider>UrkToy</provider>
            <model>cC246</model>
            <dateOfIssue>11-11-2012</dateOfIssue>
            <color>grey</color>
            <price>1100</price>
        </product>
        <product name="Dog">
            <provider>LatToy</provider>
            <model>Ld223</model>
            <dateOfIssue>03-12-2012</dateOfIssue>
            <color>white</color>
            <price>13456</price>
        </product>
    </subcategory>
    <subcategory name="Fabric toys">
        <product name="Bear">
            <provider>RusToy</provider>
            <model>BB122</model>
            <dateOfIssue>20-02-2012</dateOfIssue>
            <color>brown</color>
            <notInStock/>
        </product>
        <product name="Bird">
            <provider>BelToy</provider>
            <model>Bb110</model>
            <dateOfIssue>05-11-2012</dateOfIssue>
            <color>red</color>
            <price>500</price>
        </product>
    </subcategory>
</category>
</tar:products>
```

---

I put parameter `categoryName` in request from my previous page and it's successfully shown on my page, so problem is not in it.
Here is more info about `xsl` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:tar="http://www.epam.com/products"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.epam.com/products products.xsd ">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:param name="categoryName" select="'${categoryName}'"></xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <td align="center">
                <strong>
                    Subcategories
                            </strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:value-of select="$categoryName"/><!-- this string works -->
        <xsl:for-each select="tar:products/category[@name=$categoryName]/subcategory">
            <xsl:sort order="descending" select="count(product)"
                data-type="number" />
            <a href="controller?command=products&amp;name={@name}">
            <tr bgcolor="#F5F5F5">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                    (
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(product)" />
                    )
                </td>

            </tr>
            </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    <form method="post" action="/controller?command=back">
        <input type="submit" value="Back"/>
    </form>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Expected output,when request parameter `categoryName` equals `'Toys'`:

[image]

---

Actual output:

[image]

---

RESOVLED

In my java class I've put parameter in request before transformation, but needed simply to put it in transformator parameters:

```
transformer.setParameter("categoryName", name);
```

Comment: What is your XSLT engine/ version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to have dynamically built XPath, you will need to make use of an extension function. For example, you may be able to use the [EXSTL Dynamic Extension Function](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/index.html).

However, looking at your rather terse code sample, I am not sure you need the extra complexity in this case. Could you two lines be simplified to the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tar:products/category[@name=$categoryName]/subcategory">
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your time, but sorry, this doesn't work. It gives me blank list without any errors

Comment: btw, categoryName is a request parameter, which I'm trying to get with the help of EL. As far I understand you suggest to define it like xsl-variable. I did it but it doesn't work...

Comment: I think it would help if you expanded your question to give more details. Showing the input XML and expected output, for example, would make things more clear.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't do it. But there are vendor-specific solutions:

1. Tim's reference to EXSLT is absolutely correct. (dyn:evaluate())
2. XALAN has an evaluate function (refer: [Using dynamic xpath in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377811/using-dynamic-xpath-in-xslt))
3. Saxon has an evaluate function (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9/extensions.html#evaluate)

Also see Dimitre's answer to: [dynamic xpath in xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630023/dynamic-xpath-in-xslt)

Also note, XSLT 3.0 will have and evaluate() function (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-21/#element-evaluate)

And finally, if your dynamic XPATH to be evaluated was constrained to be of a a very simple form (eg.:  terms separated by the / operator, no axises and no predicates), then it would be possible to write a named template to perform the dynamic XPATH evaluation. But of course, what this template looks like will be highly dependant on your simple constraints on the expression.

### Example:

Take your sample dynamic path:

```
<xsl:variable name="xPath">@name='${categoryName}'</xsl:variable>
```

Suppose that the attribute name part ('name' in this sample), and the value part (I think you meant $categoryName not ${categoryName} ) are both variable, but the overall form other expression, in other words: @some-name='some-string-value' is fixed. Then you could resolve the path expression like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="name" select="'name'" /><!-- or use another computed value. -->
<xsl:variable name="value" select="'my-category-name'" /><!-- or use another computed value. -->
<xsl:for-each select="tar:products/category[@*[name()=$name][.=$value]]/subcategory">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always hard to answer a question where the requirement is written in terms of "imaginary" code - that is, code written in a language which isn't quite XSLT. So this answer assumes I have imagined correctly what you are trying to do. If that's the case, replace this:

```
<xsl:variable name="xPath">@name='${categoryName}'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="tar:products/category[$xPath]/subcategory">
```

by this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tar:products/category[@name = $categoryName]/subcategory">
```

For the more general problem, there is no standard facility in XSLT to generate XPath expressions dynamically from strings. But many products offer extension functions to achieve this: see for example saxon:evaluate().